# Changing work item type in DevOps once the state of the work item changes to 'done' using Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-flow, azure-devops

I am trying to automate a manual task in DevOps using Power Automate which is updating the work item type 'forecast' to 'task' when the state of the work item type 'forecast' is changed to 'done'.

I tried the flow and it shows that it has run successfully but it does not really update the work item type to 'task' and the work item type remains 'forecast'.

DevOps:
[image]

[image]

Power Automate flow:

[image]

.
.
.
.
.
.
[image]